# Chat moderation in a chat group (C# custom chat app)

Tags: .net, chat, chatbot

In a custom C# chat app is there a way to enable chat message moderation in a chat group to have messages from non admin members approved or blocked by admins before they’re sent or visible to the rest of the group. Any details woul be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Well, this question can only be answered by the author of that 'custom C# chat app' or by the maintainer of that chat plattform...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.